# Generate unique Identifier for table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

[image: This is a screanshot for the database]

I'm trying to create a table in SQL Server. I want to generate a unique identifier 32 bit and be the primary key.

I define it as primary key and set the type - how I can turn on the generation? How I can set it to be 32 bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a 32-bit unique identifier that is unique on each row . . . well, you have just defined the `identity` column:

```
create table . . . (
    id int identity primary key,
    . . .
);
```

This will, of course, be a sequential number, but that meets your conditions.

EDIT:

If you want `newid()` then use a default value:

```
create table . . . (
    id uniqueidentifier primary key default newid(),
    . . .
);
```

Of course, `newsequentialid()` is a better choice than `newid()`, but your sample code uses `newid()`.

A `uniqueidentifer` is 16 bytes (128 bits), so it doesn't meet your needs.  I don't think there is any other built-in mechanism for a 32-bit unique number that is guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: I want to generate the id to be a set of random character, I see something you write 
newid() with this uniqe identifier , 
but I don't know how to use it

Comment: @RandSaleh Random characters like what?

Comment: CCCCXXXXX  something like this

Comment: @RandSaleh . . . There is no guarantee of uniqueness, unless you use `identity` with a unique/primary key constraint or `newid()`.

Comment: oh yes I put newID() in the defult it's work but I must hit execute query every time I inset !
bca34fca-a907-40a1-abb2-9728c300fce5 this what I want

Comment: @RandSaleh using a GUID/UUID is most generally a bad idea, because of the randomness it can totally "unalign" index structures and cost performance in the end..

Comment: How I can view the sql statement in the sql server ? that used to create a table ?

Comment: @RaymondNijland  actully  I am solving an assignment that requiere to create a web form to insert some data, It's requiered to use unique identifier so I want it to be auto generated for each time I insert a record.how cant I make it ?
I put the newid in the defult and try to insert something locally it's work but I have to hit ecexute query in order to generate the new id, and If I insert it from the web it will crash because no data read !! and nothing generated

Comment: newID() is great in theory, BUT is an index page-fragmentation killer.

Comment: @granadaCoder . . . Of course you are right.  I used `newid()` because the OP had used that.  The gist of the answer is that `identity()` provides a 4-byte value that can be used; `uniqueidentifier`s are rather longer.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `uniqueidentifier` type or randomly generated unordered characters for the primary key is a bad idea and will actually constrain you in the future.  Yes, they are guaranteed unique but they are not guaranteed to be sequential.  Keep in mind that if you are doing any sort of clustering for high availability you do run the risk of overlapping a `uniqueidentifier`.  `NEWID()` won't create an overlap as long as it is always used on the same server.  When you change servers there isn't a guarantee it won't. It may be rare but I have seen it happen and it is not pretty when it does.

`IDENTITY` is designed for use with data types that are sequential by nature such as `INT`, `BIGINT`...  This guarantees uniqueness for the row and also gives you a sequential storage and lookup for the clustered index and prevents index fragmentation.

If you are interested in having a `uniqueidentifier` type of value to facilitate lookup from something like an API call then you are better off to have a mapping table with a natural ordered type for the primary key and the `uniqueidentifier` as a non-clustered column on the table.  That way joins can be based on the ordered primary key for all foreign tables.

Comment: actully I am solving an assignment that requiere to create a web form to insert some data, It's requiered to use unique identifier so I want it to be auto generated for each time I insert a record.how I can  make it ? I put the newid in the defult and try to insert something locally it's work but I have to hit ecexute query in order to generate the new id, and If I insert it from the web it will crash because no data read !! and nothing generate